# Android Get user location without requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I want to know the user's location, but without turning the gps on if it's not on already, means I only want to get the location is the user is using Maps or similar anyway.

If i do

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates();
```

that turns on the gps.

If I use

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();
```

this returns always the same location, even if there should be new ones because Maps is running.

Ideas anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` but this was only introduced in API level 8. 
[From Android Documentation for LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER)

> A special location provider for receiving locations without actually initiating a location fix. This provider can be used to passively receive location updates when other applications or services request them without actually requesting the locations yourself. This provider will return locations generated by other providers. You can query the getProvider() method to determine the origin of the location update. Requires the permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, although if the GPS is not enabled this provider might only return coarse fixes.

This way you are not directly requesting any location updates you only get them when some other application requests the updates.

As for `getLastKnownLocation()` again quoting the Android Documentation:

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider. This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.
>   If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

So if you are getting the same location over and over again with `getLastKnownLocation` it could be that provider is disabled and you are simply getting what the function name indicates i.e. the last known location of the device. Read the the quotes above or refer to Android documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Have your `Activity` implement `GpsStatus.Listener` and use

```
boolean isGpsStarted= false;
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:                               
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            isGpsStarted = true;
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            isGpsStarted = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` with `requestLocationUpdates` which will use WiFi and cell positioning and for better accuracy  turn on wifi programatically. Periodically check if `isGpsStarted` is true then switch to `GPS_PROVIDER` with `requestSingleUpdate`. Also check if you need to switch back to `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and periodic updates if `isGpsStarted` becomes false again.